# Webscrape with bad wifi: Can I make my scrape 'go online' again?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm doing a big python scrape for 10.000+ webpages, and it's taking me several hours to do. If I disconnect from the internet during the proces, my script just stalls, and it doesn't reconnect when the wifi is up again.

Is there any way to insert a; 'if the internet stops, then pick it up where you left off'?

Comment: Yes, of course it is! Handle the error caused by the connection dropping a loop until it goes away (you might want to incorporate an *"exponential back off"* in the loop).

Comment: This! ... sounds like what I'm looking for, but I've never handled errors before like that. If anyone can link or tell me what to search for, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: *"Python handle errors"*? Literally the first hit in Google: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 2):

There is the framework for building scrapers - [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). It has such capabilities - you can save execution state, and then resume crawling from this point (a year later, for example).

Or if you want to build it from scratch, you need to implement saving of a state of your crawler. I think it is bad idea to trying to save interpreter state, so you need to design the crawler in such way, that its state can be easily serialized.
For example, Scrapy designed in such way - crawler has some methods, it has a method, that generates initial requests. Each requests has some callback. Each callback can generate additional requests. And so on. So Scrapy's just call callbacks, and enqueue requests, and call callbacks for them. Such design makes able Scrapy to save requests queue to disk and then resume execution from last request(s).

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is there a particular argument you would set to deal with the connection dropouts?